# Sync Outlook 2013 with iTunes 12.5.1

Tags: itunes

Recently upgrade iPhone 6S to 10.1  and iTunes to 12.5.1  Mainly use iTunes to sync my Outlook contacts and calendar via USB cable only (not Wi-Fi).  Appears to begin sync and stops part ways through process and sounds as though sync is complete.  Do not use iCloud for sync.

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't want to use iCloud, you can try 3-rd party software called AkrutoSync. Unfortunately, there's no way for syncing over USB, only via Wi-Fi or over the Internet. The best part is that this software works with iPhone's native apps which I found very convenient. Here's a link to their website: http://www.akruto.com/sync-iphone-with-outlook/

The bad thing is that you have to reconfigure this software each time you want to switch between syncing over the Internet to syncing via Wi-Fi.